# How to uncollapse columns in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am continuing work a DB to PHPExcel generated spreadsheet. The last remaining problem I am having is that all the rows but the last one are collapsed when the spreadsheet opens. I need them all expanded. Right now the user has to grab the top border and drag it down to expose the row above it. I've tried:

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row)->setVisible(true);
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row)>setCollapsed(false);
```

$row is the current row number.

Comment: If you're creating a new worksheet, then rows should not be collapsed at all by default: how are you creating this worksheet?

Comment: $phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Search Results");
$phpExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("example.com");
$phpExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("example.com");
$phpExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Search Results");
$phpExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Search Results");          
$phpExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Spreadsheet of search results created by example.com");
$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: I've never come across that problem before: PHPExcel should only collapse rows if you explicitly collapse them... what version of PHPExcel are you using?

Comment: Very odd, will try to recreate: which Writer are you using?

Comment: $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel5");
$objWriter->save("test.xls");

Comment: @MarkBaker it is working in Excel. It is not working in Calc in Libre Office. Sorry, I had switched systems and didn't realize I was on the Libre Office system (focused on the code). It is a problem with Calc however.

Comment: That could take some time delving into the source of Open/Libre Office Calc to determine why it chooses to compress the rows; I'm unlikely to be able to fix it quickly

Comment: The main target is excel. It would be nice if it was fixed in Calc but not urgent. Thanks for your work on this code.